# html source is not always present in angular js page via selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

Im trying to scrape a site that is mostly angularjs.
My basic code is shown below.

I am passing in parameters, getting back the html and then checking if there is pagination by looking for an element i know exists with the id "next".

The problem is that, for a page i know the "next" element is on, my code only finds it some of the time, others it cant see it at all.

I think it may be something to do wtih the fact that im checking before the html has been rendered, but im not sure why it would work some of the time.

Any pointers or advice are appreciated.

```
def getBrowser():
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')

return browser


def getPage(browser):
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    return soup

webBrowser = getBrowser()
webBrowser.get("my page")
mainPage = getPage(webBrowser)

pagination = mainPage.select('#next')

#this value is randomly populated, and randomly a blank list.
print(pagination)
```

Comment: You're supposed to either wait N amount of time, or possibly await on an element being present before you take the page source... Where do you specify the page to load? Or are you just waiting for the home page? Appears to be quite a bit of code missing here that will show what you've instructed your browser to retrieve...

Comment: just the actual link missing, i dont want to post the main link. this is pretty much it though. I tried adding a sleep() command, up to crazy values like 20 seconds, it doesnt make a difference. even without sleep, i "randomly" can get the "next"  element.

Comment: found a resolution. needed a 2nd sleep(), one after webBrowser.get("my page") for about 5 seconds and one after mainPage = getPage(webBrowser) for an additional 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the sleeps, find the element using selenium's WebdriverWait().until along with the visibility_of_element_located or similar Expected Condition. It stops waiting the moment it finds the desired element, and you can catch the TimeoutException if it doesn't find it and raise a nice readable exception so you'll know exactly why your attempt failed, not just tomorrow but years from now. The Timeout and Poll times are all customizable.

Each time you find yourself reaching for time.sleep, ask yourself if you are facing the 1% of automation use cases where it is considered the best approach.